# Организация списка литературы на SO (вопрос к модераторам)

Tags: предложение, учебные-материалы

Обнаружил, что по определенной теме, а именно по [метке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) **"Искусственный интеллект"** отсутствует качественная подборка литературы и прочих ресурсов, вернее, вопрос-ответ, содержащий список книг, как, например, такой [вопрос - ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1). Поскольку я работаю с ИИ, если подробнее, то в области проектирования архитектуры мультиагентных систем для лингвистического анализа ЕЯ, у меня уже накопился довольно большой список разной литературы + я могу дополнительно попросить ссылки на ресурсы у коллег с кафедры.

Мой **вопрос** в том, можно ли на SO открыть вопрос-ответ для накопления ресурсов по этой теме и если *да*, то как правильно это сделать? В частности, как оформить, какие правила по ссылкам и т.п. Из того, что есть на сайте, я нашел только такой полумертвый [вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65273/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83).

Comment: Создаете вопрос с примерным шаблонным содержанием и нужными метками, пример:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/191482 ........ пишется общий ответ. Затем добавляется ссылка на этот вопрос-ответ сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F  и можно модератора попросить сделать вопрос тоже общим и залоченным. всё.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нашел вот этот вопрос-ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-машинному-обучению - возник такой вопрос: есть некоторые ресурсы, которые будут продублированы в моей подборке  (например, книга Рассела-Норвига). Однако все мои новые ресурсы не будет правильным добавлять в подборку по машинному обучению, поскольку там превалируют математические алгоритмы, нейросети, байесовские модели, статистический подход, распознавание/классификация. А тематика ИИ более обширна (например, я хочу добавить ресурсы об обработке ЕЯ

Comment: и материалы по системе IBM Watson. Тут нельзя сказать, что лингвистический анализ ляжет в одно место со статистическим, приведенным в подборке «Машинное обучение», - это вообще конкурирующий подход. Плюс я хочу добавить ресурсы по архитектурам экспертных систем, баз знаний и агентным системам, а это тоже не стоит класть в одну корзину с «математическим анализом данных». В общем, вопрос в том, допускается ли дублирование 3-4 ресурсов?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и второй вопрос: допускается ли в ответе приведение ссылок на статьи, сборники трудов с конференций, видеолекции и т.п. ресурсы не книжного формата?

Comment: @Jenssen, Обычно - нет (особенно видео не приветствуют), но если очень уж хороший и монументальный материал, то можно.